# Given a return from os.listdir('.') how can i count the amount of times the extension .pdf appears?

Tags: python, pdf

```
a = os.listdir('.')

a = ['60598-2-1.pdf', 'pdfsorter.py']
```

When i try to use this: `a.count("pdf")` it returns 0, it only works with the complete text.

Example:

```
a.count("pdf") returns 0

a.count("60598-2-1.pdf") returns 1
```

Solution:

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832438/8641804
```

Comment: `count` returns the number of occurrences by value. It doesn't search by partial strings

Comment: Have you considered using `glob.glob('*.pdf')` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['60598-2-1.pdf', 'pdfsorter.py']
count = sum(1 for item in a if item.endswith('.pdf'))
```

Comment: @sapocacona  np :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `glob` module from python standard library.

```
>>> import glob    
>>> count = len(glob.glob("*.pdf")) # will gives you the count of pdf files in the cwd.
```